# "Flatten" Nested Object for Data Table

Tags: reactjs, datatable, jsx

#### Issue

I want to implement a data table on my project and the data I provide for the table looks like this:

```
data=[
  {
    key: "value",
    anotherKey: "bar",
  },
  {
    key: "value",
    anotherKey: {
      "nestedKey": "nestedValue",
      "foo": "bar"
    },
  },
  {
    key: "value",
    anotherKey: "foo",
  },
]
```

So basically I have an array of objects and *some* of the objects inside might contain nested data which also has to be rendered to the table.

Now, since I'm only "allowed" to pass an array of key/value paired objects to the table, this will break.

#### What i try to achieve

I want the nested objects to be in a renderable way so they can get rendered by the data table.

#### What I tried

```
const transformedData = data.map(d => {
  return Object.keys(d).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof key === "object") {
      d[key] = <p>{d[key]}</p>
    } 
  })
})
```

Unfortunately this didn't work out at all.

I am pretty sure that I am extremely overcomplicating things here and I'd appreciate any help. I have looked on google before but didn't find any reasonable answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show us some output that you want please ?

Comment: @ThanyathonPornsawatchai my nested object should be rendered e.g. as a list inside one table cell. So instead of having it as one string. i'd like to have it as a list. This is how it looks atm: https://www.screencast.com/t/LK0lfvgOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were going in the right direction, by extending your solution I was able to come up with this

```
transformedData = data.map( v => {
    let d = {...v}
    Object.keys(d).forEach(key => {
        if (typeof d[key] === "object") {
            d[key] = Object.keys(d[key]).reduce((acc, nestedKey) => {
                return acc + '<p>' + nestedKey + ':' + d[key][nestedKey] + '</p>'
            }, '')
        }
    });
    return d;
})
```

It is working, but I am sure there can be a better solution than this.

Comment: got it to work by wrapping the `d[key] = ...` part in a `<ul dangerouslySetInnerHTML .../>` :-) thanks!